# How to add URL queryString in Vue with no page refresh?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to add query string to url in vue component.
as an example, This is my url: `https://example.com/users/`
I want to concat `?f%5Bfullname-lk,email-lk%5D=Atousa` to url with no refresh page.
I need to have `https://example.com/users/?f%5Bfullname-lk,email-lk%5D=Atousa`
If this be in url my component will be refreshed.

I used `this.$router.push({ query: ?f%5Bfullname-lk,email-lk%5D=Atousa })`, but it gives me `https://example.com/users/?query=f%5Bfullname-lk,email-lk%5D=Atousa` which I don't.

And `window.location.assign` refreshes the page.

Comment: How about `this.$router.push({ 'f%5Bfullname-lk,email-lk%5D': 'Atousa' })`?

Comment: It would work. But I don't know what my keys are, I get various query strings. I need a way to change query string to query object using no new component, or another way.